# SSE bug in my CPU?

Tags: visual-c++, sse, simd

I'm very stumped.

When I run this code in Visual C++ 2008:

```
__m128i a, b;
a.m128i_u64[0] = 1;
b.m128i_u64[0] = 0;
a.m128i_u64[1] = 0;
b.m128i_u64[1] = 0;
printf("%d\n", _mm_testc_si128(a, b));
```

it prints `1`. Which is contrary to what I expect, because it's supposed to be 1 only if `a` and `b` are the same.

How is this possible? Is there a bug in my CPU or in Visual C++ 2008 or something else?

Comment: The instruction you try to use is SSE4 (!) - are you sure your CPU supports that ? IF yes, what happen if you move the call `int res = _mm_testc_si128(a, b);` before the `printf` and use `res` in the `printf` instead ?

Comment: @Yahia: Yes, my CPU supports SSE4, up to SSE4.2. The same thing happens when I use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know for a fact that a lot of SSE4.1 intrinsics are broken in VS2008. They fixed them for VS2010. In VS2010 (no SP), some of the AVX intrinsics are broken. They fixed those in VS2010 SP1.

I've never used the `_mm_testc_si128` intrinsic, so I don't know if that's another intrinsic that's broken in VS2008. But I've seen numerous cases where insert/extract intrinsics were broken.

**EDIT :** I just tested this in VS2010 SP1, it also gives 1.

Now that I look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513983.aspx), it looks like it "should" be returning 1.

> Return value
>
> 1 if all the bits set in b are set in a; otherwise 0.

So I don't think it's a bug in this case.

Comment: OMFG goddammit... I was pulling my hair out and using the local MSDN library for VS 2008 instead of the online one, and it says the return value is `1 if a and b are bitwise identical; 0 otherwise.` Wow. Thanks. +1 (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb513983(v=vs.90).aspx)).

Comment: lol, looks like they really borked their VS2008 documentation... :P